# OpenFeint Xcode 4 integration, prefix header not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, openfeint

I just upgraded to Xcode 4, deleted the OpenFeint folder and added the new 2.9.1 framework according to this [readme](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/readme-openfeint-ios-sdk-2-9-1/).
Then I deleted the "build"-Folder (that is now located in ~/library/Developer/...) and rebuilt the application but always get the following error:

```
/Users/k****/Documents/Tactica/Tactica_Prefix.pch:5:30: error: OpenFeintPrefix.pch: No such file or directory
```

When I have a look into OpenFeint.framework/headers there is clearly a file "OpenFeintPrefix.pch" included.

Any Idea why Xcode doesn't find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add OpenFeint/ before any includes, like

```
#import "OpenFeint/OpenFeintPrefix.pch"
```

This should do it :)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, I totally forgot !

Answer (score 0):

I used OpenFeint a long time ago. The most errors I can solve with redo the instructions.

Also with updating to Xcode 4 al paths gets changed and Xcode has problems with finding files from old projects.

I recommend you to redo the instructions and if it didn't work, I'd recreate the project and add OF again, the problems should be gone then.

Answer (score -1):

> When I have a look into
>   OpenFeint.framework/headers there is
>   clearly a file "OpenFeintPrefix.pch"
>   included.

The most obvious point would be, are you looking at that location through finder or Xcode.
The file must be included in your xcode project itself rather then just in that folder on the computer?

Comment: Of course, I expand the framework inside xcode, because as you say, I wanted to see whether that file is a part of the project.

Comment: The only other things that have given me that type of error is if I also have a reference to it as a static framework that is set wrongly. The readme says it now includes a static framework so? [link](http://support.openfeint.com/dev/readme-openfeint-ios-sdk-2-9-1/#changelog) I'm sorry i can't be more helpful, it seems like a really odd/annoying error.